# Using PowerShell to create and add class libraries to a solution

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate some of the tasks I perform on each web project. What I want is a PoSH script that I can run on a new solution that will:

- load the solution contained in the scripts current directory.
- create new projects for the loaded solution and add them to the solution.
- create some classes and add them to each of the projects.

So far I have a simple script (shown below) that finds and opens the local solution file.

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
Set-Location $dir

$solution = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{($_.Extension -eq ".sln")}

if ($solution.Count -eq 0)
{
    "Please place this script in the folder containing you solution file."
    break;
}

$dteObj = New-Object -ComObject "VisualStudio.DTE"
$dteObj.Solution.Open($solution.FullName)
```

How can I now create new projects and add them to the solution?

Comment: [MSDN: How to programmatically Create Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Andy that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to run your code in ISE, why do I get $dteObj.Solution is null?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://studioshell.codeplex.com/ by Jim Christopher.

Answer (score 0):

To create a project , call GetProjectTemplate, and then pass the returned template paths to AddFromTemplate.

Try this in Package Manager Console.

```psh
    #Create a Console Project
    $csTemplatePath = $dte.Solution.GetProjectTemplate("ConsoleApplication.zip", "CSharp")
    $csPrjPath = "C:\\Projects\\SolutionName\\ConsoleApplication1"
    $dte.Solution.AddFromTemplate($csTemplatePath, $csPrjPath, "ConsoleApplication1", 'false')

    #Create a C# class
    $itemPath  = $dte.Solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("Class.zip", "CSharp")
    $prj = Get-Project
    $prjItem = $prj.ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate($itemPath, "Project.cs")
```